# iOS ObjectiveC: Support Right To Left

Tags: ios, objective-c, right-to-left, arabic-support

To support the Right To Left on my app, I'm using this instructions:

```
[[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];

[[UIStackView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];

[UITextView appearance].textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

But I have a lot of problems:
 -I don't understand how to refresh the UI if I need to apply the new alignment in the current view.
 -In a collection view the alignment doesn't change even if I use:

```
[[UICollectionView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
```

so I decided to use:

```
self.sectionsCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

and:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1);
```

It works, but if I push another view and after I pop to the view with the collection view, it's again aligned to the left until I tap into the section header, after the tap it goes to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Apple's documentation,

> By default, text alignment in iOS is natural; in OS X, it’s left.
>   Using natural text alignment aligns text on the left in a
>   left-to-right language, and automatically mirrors the alignment for
>   right-to-left languages. For example, if you set the alignment of an
>   `NSMutableParagraphStyle` object using the setAlignment: method, pass
>   `NSNaturalTextAlignment` as the parameter.

```
[[(NSMutableParagraphStyle *)paraStyle setAlignment:NSNaturalTextAlignment];
```

> However, if you want to align a control to the right in a
>   left-to-right language (and to the left in a right-to-left language),
>   get the layout direction, as described in Getting the Layout
>   Direction, and set the alignment to `NSLeftTextAlignment` for a
>   right-to-left language.

For more details, please refer [Supporting Right-to-Left Languages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH17-SW1)

Comment: This is what I did, but it's not working on this view.   ![Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=132jEFvqfv5OgVnUdbbUx2e4ijE2I_zC0).